# Multiple rows to one row query

Tags: mysql, join, row, left-join

On my database when i do this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN usersToStrategy uts on uts.userID = u.userID
LEFT JOIN strategy s on uts.stratID  = s.stratID
```

I get the following results:

```
 userID    username  fName   utsID  userID   stratID  stratID   stratName
   1       nlubin     Neal    66      1        4       4         s3
   1       nlubin     Neal    65      1        3       3         s5
   1       nlubin     Neal    64      1        2       2         s2
   1       nlubin     Neal    63      1        1       1         s1
```

How do I structure my query that instead of getting those four rows (for only one user) I get one row for the user with all of the user's strats in one cell in the row like this:

```
 userID    username  fName      stratNames
   1       nlubin     Neal    s3, s5, s2, s1
```

I can give you as much information that I can within reason to help with the question.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it in SQL instead of your application? What if a stratName contains a comma?

Comment: @Dan -- It matters the speed of the application, it is usually faster to do the query on the sql side.   I am using a hypothetical, the result set does not have to be with a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT userID, username, fName, GROUP_CONCAT(stratNames SEPARATOR ', ') AS strats
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN usersToStrategy uts on uts.userID = u.userID
LEFT JOIN strategy s on uts.stratID  = s.stratID  
GROUP BY userID, username, fName
```

Answer (score 2):

You use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: how would i use it in my example?

Comment: I know you haven't read the webpage yet, so are you going to hire me to do it for you, or are you at least going to attempt to read the page and modify your query?

Comment: Because the JOINs have nothing to do with it. All you have to do is select GROUP_CONCAT(stratNames) instead of selecting the column normally.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` like this

```
SELECT userID,
username,
fName,   
GROUP_CONCAT(stratNames)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN usersToStrategy uts on uts.userID = u.userID 
LEFT JOIN strategy s on uts.stratID  = s.stratID   
GROUP BY username;
```