# How to select all data from all tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table called stories. It only has one row---story.

How do I return all the stories in a, concatenated in a single string variable?

I thought it would be merely

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from stories");
```

Incorrect?

Comment: all stories?? you said it has only one row?

Comment: @ferozakbar - I think he meant one column.

Comment: You can check below if it fits for you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781103/multiple-rows-to-one-row-query

Comment: As it stands i only have one row and 1 column

Comment: if you only 1 row and column,then what is there to concatenate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(story) FROM stories;
```

This will return a concatenated string with each story separated by an ',' character.

If you would like to remove the separator you can use the following syntax:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(story SEPARATOR '') FROM stories;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(story_column) as stories  from stories
```

Here **story_column** is name of column where stories are saved in table.

It will give you all stories in a single string with concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you question, but this may help you.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`col1`, ' ', `col2`,' ',`col3`) FROM `table`
```