# displaying results from many to many linked table

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have the following tables and I want to display all the genres for one game on one row. There is a `game` table with a GameID and GameTitle:

**genre Table**

```
GenreID   Genre_Name   
----------------------
1         Action     
2         Third Person     
3         Open World
```

**game_genre table**

```
GameGameID   GenreGenreID  
-------------------------
197          1
197          2     
197          3
```

This is the result I got:

```
GameID    GameTitle      Genre 
-------------------------------------  
197       Watch Dogs     Third Person
197       Watch Dogs     Action
197       Watch Dogs     Open World
```

Query:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(Genre_Name) 
  FROM game
  JOIN game_genre ON game.GameID = game_genre.GameGameID 
  JOIN genre ON game_genre.GenreGenreID = genre.GenreID`
```

How do I get a the table to appear like this?

```
GameID    GameTitle                 Genre 
--------------------------------------------------------------------  
197       Watch Dogs                Third Person, Action, Open World
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781103/multiple-rows-to-one-row-query

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimal way to concatenate/aggregate strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639262/optimal-way-to-concatenate-aggregate-strings)

Comment: Just add GROUP_CONCAT(Genre_Name SEPARATOR ', ').  Dupe of the first SO comment but not the second.